# Active Admin rails, new button to an existing action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, activeadmin, actionmailer

I'm trying add a new button(Resend Email) to an existing(Send Email) method/route on Active Admin rails. I have done these kind of tasks on a normal rails with MVC architecture. Where I used to add the required route path in a html.erb file. I'm finding it quiet difficult to implement the same on Active Admin since it doesn't have that MVC look.
On **routes.rb**  file I have

**routes.rb**

```
    Rails.application.routes.draw do
       mount Bootsy::Engine => '/bootsy', as: 'bootsy'
       devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config
       ActiveAdmin.routes(self)
       devise_for :users,controllers: {registrations: 'users/registrations',sessions: 'users/sessions',confirmations: 'users/confirmations'}
    end
```

Here `confirmations: 'users/confirmations'` is used to send Email Verfication mail to the users. That's working fine. Some users forget to look into their email. So I'm trying to create a "Resend Email" button on the ActiveAdmin file, which on  submitting sends the verification email mail again. 
What path should I set inorder to send the mail again. I'm new to active-admin rails. Your help would be much appreciated.

**User.rb**

```
ActiveAdmin.register User, :as => 'User' do
  action_item only: :show do
    link_to('Resend Email', )
  end
end
```

**user_mailer.rb**

```
def confirmation_instructions(record, token, opts={})
    @system_email = SystemEmail.find_by(title: 'Email Verification')
    @subject =  @system_email.try(:subject).to_s
    @subject = "Email Verification" if @subject.blank?

    opts = {subject: @subject}
    @token = token
    devise_mail(record, :confirmation_instructions, opts)
end
```